# Counting certain elements of a generalized symmetric group

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be the wreath product of the cyclic group of order $n$ with the symmetric group $S_r$. The group $G$ acts on the set $X=\{1,\ldots, n\}\times\{1,\ldots, r\}$ in a natural way. How many elements of $G$ move every element of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $f(n,r)$ you are looking for should be
$$f(n,r)=\sum_{i=0}^r\;(n-1)^i\cdot n^{r-i}\cdot D(r, i)$$
where $D(r,i)$ is the number of [*partial derangements*](http://oeis.org/A098825), i.e. the number of permutations $\in S_r$ fixing exactly $i$ elements.

Comment: Shouldn't the $i$-th term be $(n-1)^in^{r-i}D(r,i)$?

Comment: @352506: Yes, of course you are right; I got "fixing" and "moving" mixed up - I'll edit my post!